# Magento 2 table name for product visibility

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

In which db table magento is saving the product's visibility such as catalog/search , catalog, search, Not visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_code` = 'visibility'; # Example : attribute_id = 96

SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
WHERE `attribute_id` = 96 
    AND entity_id = '1'; # entity_id = Your Product Id
```

Visiblity

```
1 => Not Visible Individually
2 => Catalog
3 => Search
4 => Catalog, Search
```

Comment: It is best to also use `entity_type_id = 'product'` when searching the `eav_attribute` table as it is possible to have another "visibility" attribute (or if searching for something like status)

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

This problem arises because the Scope of Visibility attribute is Store View by default. This means that it’s value is set differently for each store.

**Solution:**

**There are two solutions:-**

1) Either, change the Visibility of the product to Nowhere for each store you have.

– While editing product, in the top left corner, you will see ‘Choose Store View’

– Choose the store where you want the product visibility to Nowhere
– Now, edit the visibility to Nowhere and Save the product

2) The second solution is to directly change the **Visibility** attribute Scope.

– **Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes**

– **Edit Visibility attribute**

– **Change the Scope to ‘Global’**